# How Simulate "Enter Key Hit" Using With Both Javascript & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How simulate **Enter Key Hit** using with both `javascript` & `jquery`?
I know js has been deprecated but I need it.
I found many threads about simulate KeyPress **EVENT**, but I am talking about simulate enter key press just like a human do using with js & jquery.
how can I do that?
this is my textBox and I want to hit enter on it by codes :

```
var texts = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (var i = 0 ; i < texts.length ; i++)
{
  if (texts[i].getAttribute("id") == "my_goal_textBox")
  {
    alert("hi");
    texts[i].value = "hello";
    //->Now here i want to hit enter key programatically, how?  
 }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

Comment: @Satpal, yes. enter on textbox.

Comment: You can do `texts[i].value += "\r\n";`

Comment: @Satpal : no. i need to simulate enter key press, just like a human press that key by his/her hand...

Comment: @Moonlight—you can [dispatch a keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) with appropriate parameters from a particular target element, however browsers may not treat it exactly like user input. You can't fool them, they *know* where the event came from. See also [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).